# Get max width of uinavigationItem.titleView?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, frame, uinavigationitem, titlebar

I have a custom titleView that I need to set the max width for. That would be the screen width - width of left item (back title, button or nil) - width of right item (button or nil). How can I determine this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't the navigationbar set the width to its maximum automatically? I mean, I'm sure the sizeThatFits: method of your custom titleView is called. Maybe this is a good starting point.

Comment: It doesn't set the width automatically. I can call sizeToFit which calls sizeThatFits after setting it, but I don't know what to return from sizeThatFits. Where do I get the maximum width from?

Comment: I haven't tested it myself, but since title views are, actually, resized in order to fit and to be centered between the left and right navigation items, I expect the sizeThatFits message to be actually sent by the navigation bar itself to the titleView. Isn't it the case?

Comment: I don't think so, but I'm not sure. But either way, what do I return from sizeThatFits?

Comment: The parameter sent to this method should be the value you are looking for.

Comment: The value passed to sizeThatFits: has a width that doesn't account for the left and right bars.

Comment: why this answer is marked as correct one when it doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 6):

```
_segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGFLOAT_MAX, _segmentedControl.frame.size.height);

[self.navigationItem setTitleView:_segmentedControl];
```

Setting CGFLOAT_MAX as width for the navigationItem title view use the maximum space available between the left item and the right item.

Comment: This worked for me on iOS < 11 (the view was sized automatically for me in iOS 11)

Answer (score -1):

Set titleView width to more width than needed for maximum screen width and navigationbar resizes width to fit screen. If there are left or right UIBarButtonItem, then titleView resizes relative to them. Try rotating screen and see for yourself.

```
func setTitleView(){
    guard let navFrame = navigationController?.navigationBar.frame else{
        return
    }
    let myView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: navFrame.width*3, height: navFrame.height))
    myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
    self.navigationItem.titleView = myView
}
```

Comment: why * by 3? can someone explain?